# Apache randomly predictable slow loading

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have multiple virtual hosts set up. On one of them, let's say three out of ten page loads are basically instant. The other seven always take (pretty much) exactly 5 seconds of server lag (as opposed to data transfer).

It doesn't matter which page is loading, or whether or not it's a Drupal page.

There are a lot of requests each second, and I'm wondering if Apache is putting requests on standby until it's finished with the current queue, or something along those lines?

Cheers

Comment: Isn't something that is randomly predictable an oxymoron?

Comment: I guess so, what I meant was that it was random when it happened but you knew it would happen soon ;-)

Comment: Perhaps "recurring" or "recurrent" would be a better word.

Answer (score 0):

It could be server queueing (server-status should tell you that), but from the precision and consistency of the delay, I'd be inclined to think it's probably rDNS lookups timing out -- which is why everyone turns it off (with `HostnameLookups Off`).

Comment: How would I turn off rDNS lookups then? :P

Comment: Hmm...hang on it looks like it is definitely a problem induced by high traffic from multiple sources. So I bet it must be server queuing. Maybe I could try raising the queue length, only thing is this is a single core 2.2GHz CPU...

Comment: If your server is overloaded, reduce the load (optimize, load balance) or get a bigger server.

Comment: Sadly that's not an option so for now, I'm just going to live with the lag. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_status.html) to help debug the issue. It gives a good incite into what apache is up to, and can often indicate where to start debugging a problem (script/apache config/etc).

Comment: I heard about that but could never get it going.

Comment: @Fela - it should be pretty simple, once you have the module loaded just drop this config in: http://pastebin.com/vz5H5QyW

Comment: Heh, I made a new directory and put that in the .htaccess and it finally works :P Thanks :)